# Can you add entries to fstab with a GUI in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, cifs

I am sick of always having to google for the process of adding a drive to the `fstab` using text editor.

Is there a way to add say a CIFS samba share to the `fstab` with a Ubuntu GUI? Like Windows' map network path functionality.

Comment: How about pysdm https://pysdm.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On Ubuntu you can edit your `fstab` using the `gnome-disk-utility`. From the terminal run `gnome-disks` or type `Disks` from the dash. Select the disk then the partition, from the **Option** menu select **Edit Mount Options**.

Comment: No this does not work. Using Gnome Disks utility, I tried using change to the auto-mount switch and check-boxes to auto-mount instead. It does not change anything in fstab. Also root password is not passed. When I manually mount the drives, it asks for the root password. That has to be passed along and well anyhow it is a failure.  Also looking at `fstab` after changes reveal that nothing was added or removed.  
I am using MX-16 Linux, but it appears to be the same for most any Linux.

Comment: If your password entry dialog is less-than-functional, you can run the utility as root from the terminal by issuing `sudo gnome-disk-utility`. This will bypass the broken GUI password prompt.

Answer (score 2):

[KDE Partition Manager](https://www.kde.org/applications/system/kdepartitionmanager/) is an alternative to gnome-disk-utility , it can be installed on [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/admin/partitionmanager) and [debian](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/admin/partitionmanager) based distro.

> file, disk and partition management for KDE
>
> Partition Manager is a utility program to help you manage the disk devices, partitions and file systems on your computer. It allows you to easily create, copy, move, delete, resize without losing data, backup and restore partitions.
>
> Partition Manager supports a large number of file systems, including ext2/3/4, reiserfs, NTFS, FAT16/32, jfs, xfs and more. Note that to gain support for a specific file system other than ext2/3/4, you should install the corresponding suggested package.
>
> Partition Manager is based on libparted (like gparted) and makes use of the KDE libraries for its user interface.

To install KDE Partition Manager:

```
sudo apt install partitionmanager
```