# Can you manage the entire fstab file with a GUI?

Tags: fstab, gui

I hate constantly having to wrestle with a command line editor and looking things up when managing my fstab file. Is there a GUI that will let me do it by clicking on things?

---

**Why `gnome-disk-utility` does not help:**

There's a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/370316/217968) but it's actually very different. The accepted answer suggests using `gnome-disk-utility`. This allows you to *add* generated entries for the selected partition. However, I am not asking about just *adding* entries, but managing all of the existing entries.

Here is an incomplete list of what I want to do, that `gnome-disk-utility` can't:

- List all entries in `fstab`
- Parse all the options of an arbitrary `fstab` entry (even if the partition does not currently exist) and explain what they mean
- Edit an existing `fstab` entry (even if the partition does not currently exist)
- Find duplicate/redundant `fstab` entries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you add entries to fstab with a GUI in ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370316/can-you-add-entries-to-fstab-with-a-gui-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Dupe voters: Please read the question carefully. As I say, **adding** is very different from **managing/listing**.